# DataTable.PrimaryKey is populated with unique clustered index, not primary key

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have a SQL Server table `MyTable` with a primary key set for column `A` and also unique clustered index set for columns `B` and `C`.

After this call:

```
(new SqlDataAdapter(new SqlCommand($"select top 0 * from MyTable", conn))).FillSchema(theDataTable, SchemaType.Mapped);
```

the `theDataTable` has its `.PrimaryKey` set to columns `B` and `C`, not `A`.
Why is this so?

Comment: Are columns B and C not nullable? You have UNIQUE Clustered index so it could be treated as PK as well.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda they are not nullable, but in the SQL server PK is definitely set to column A...

Comment: According to [FillSchema(DataTable, SchemaType, IDbCommand, CommandBehavior)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.fillschema?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_Common_DbDataAdapter_FillSchema_System_Data_DataTable_System_Data_SchemaType_System_Data_IDbCommand_System_Data_CommandBehavior_): *"If both primary key columns and unique columns are returned, the primary key columns are used as the primary key columns for the DataTable."* Could you post the full DDL of `MyTable`?

Comment: @Larnu I'll double-check this on a simplier table and if issue still remains then I'll post it here.

Comment: Wait, further reading  *"If a unique clustered index is defined on a column or columns in a SQL Server table and the primary key constraint is defined on a separate set of columns, then the names of the columns in the clustered index will be returned. o return the name or names of the primary key columns, use a query hint with the SELECT statement that specifies the name of the primary key index. For more information about specifying query hints, see [Query Hint (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms181714.aspx)."* Seems the behaviour is documented.

Comment: @Larnu errr, I should have RTFM'ed before posting this... thank you! I'll accept it as an answer if you post it.

Comment: That's ok, if you're looking to get the Primary key back in your query, then the real answer here is getting the right Query hint. I've only quoted the documentation to you after a (quick) Google, but I'll add as an answer anyway, as it'll likely be useful for future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've commented, this is actually covered in the documentation [FillSchema(DataTable, SchemaType, IDbCommand, CommandBehavior)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.fillschema?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_Common_DbDataAdapter_FillSchema_System_Data_DataTable_System_Data_SchemaType_System_Data_IDbCommand_System_Data_CommandBehavior_):

> FillSchema also configures the PrimaryKey and Constraints properties
>   according to the following rules:
>
> - If one or more primary key columns are returned by the SelectCommand, they are used as the primary key columns for the
>     DataTable.
> - If no primary key columns are returned but unique columns are, the unique columns are used as the primary key if, and only if, all the
>     unique columns are nonnullable. If any of the columns are nullable, a
>     UniqueConstraint is added to the ConstraintCollection, but the
>     PrimaryKey property is not set.
> - If both primary key columns and unique columns are returned, the primary key columns are used as the primary key columns for the
>     DataTable.
>
> Note that primary keys and unique constraints are added to the
>   ConstraintCollection according to the preceding rules, but other
>   constraint types are not added.
>
> If a unique clustered index is defined on a column or columns in a SQL
>   Server table and the primary key constraint is defined on a separate
>   set of columns, then the names of the columns in the clustered index
>   will be returned. To return the name or names of the primary key
>   columns, use a query hint with the SELECT statement that specifies the
>   name of the primary key index. For more information about specifying
>   query hints, see [Query Hint (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms181714.aspx).

If you do need to get the Primary Key details from `.PrimaryKey` then you'll need to use a hint as the documentation suggests. Without the DDL (including indexes) of your table though, we won't be able to tell you what the hint would be.